# Why does a single assignment to one 2d array cell fill two cells at once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have this code from [this leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-284/problems/count-artifacts-that-can-be-extracted/):

```
function digArtifacts(n: number, artifacts: number[][], dig: number[][]): number {
    
    const land: boolean[][] = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(false))
    console.log(land)
    
    dig.forEach(spot => {
        console.log(spot, spot[0], spot[1])
        land[spot[0]][spot[1]] = true
        console.log(land)
    })
    
    console.log(land)
    return 0

};
```

With this input

```
n = 2
artifacts = [[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1]]
dig = [[0,0],[0,1]]
```

With this stdout:

```
[ [ false, false ], [ false, false ] ]

[ 0, 0 ] 0 0

[ [ true, false ], [ true, false ] ] **but expected => [ [ true, false ], [ false, false ] ]

[ 0, 1 ] 0 1

[ [ true, true ], [ true, true ] ] **but expected [ [ true, true ], [ false, false ] ]
[ [ true, true ], [ true, true ] ] **but expected [ [ true, true ], [ false, false ] ]
```

Why do `land[1][0]` === true and `land[1][1]` === true when they are never accessed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
  new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(false))
```

fills the new outer array with `n` copies of **the same array**. The argument to the outer `.fill()` is computed once, so there's only one array involved for the second dimension.

You can create multiple arrays, one for each row:

```
const land: boolean[][] = new Array(n);
land.fill("dummy value");
land.forEach((_, i, rows) =>
  rows[i] = new Array(n);
  rows[i].fill(false)
);
```

In the (edited) code, the outer array is first filled with a dummy value. That's necessary because `.forEach()` will skip uninitialized entries in an array. Alternatively, a simple `for` loop could be used, though unless `n` is enormous it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: ‍♂️ of course. So all arrays in my 2d array were using the same pointer to a single array. THANKS!

Comment: That code is not quite right; fixing it now.

Comment: @Pointy `Array.from({length: n}, () => new Array(n).fill(false))` should fix it

Comment: @sschwei1 yea that would work too

Comment: @Pointy curious why an enormous `n` would influence choice of .forEach over a simple for loop? I know I read somewhere that one is faster, is that the case here? and can you say which is faster if so?

Comment: @Dozie well you're right; if you're going to end up filling the outer array with a bunch of rows, the initial dummy `.fill()` wouldn't make things materially worse;  if `n` is too big it's going to fail anyway. (Here, "too big" means like a million x million matrix or something like that.)